# Constraints regarding NEW and OLD in MySQL triggers

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, triggers

In the book "MySQL Administrator's Bible", the authors dicuss some constraints regarding the combination of events, timing and the key-words NEW and OLD in triggers. What they say is the following:

-BEFORE INSERT: NEW is supported with BEFORE INSERT. BEFORE does not support OLD.

-AFTER INSERT: AFTER does not support NEW. It does not make sense to use OLD with AFTER INSERT.

-BEFORE UPDATE: NEW is supported with BEFORE UPDATE. BEFORE does not support OLD.

-AFTER UPDATE: AFTER does not support NEW. AFTER UPDATE supports OLD.

-BEFORE DELETE: It does not make sense to use NEW with BEFORE DELETE. BEFORE does not support OLD.

-AFTER DELETE: AFTER does not support NEW. OLD is supported with AFTER DELETE.

That is, according to the book, for example, I cannot use NEW when I'm using AFTER. However, in the following trigger this is exactly what I'm doing. If some new employee is inserted, I store this employee in a backup table called employee_history.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER insert_emplyee_history
AFTER INSERT ON EMPLOYEE
FOR EACH ROW
 INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_HISTORY VALUES (NEW.NOME,NEW.SSN,NEW.SALARIO,NEW.DNO);
```

This trigger works as expected in MySQL 5.7.

Is the book wrong?
Maybe these constraints have changed in the last versions (5.7).

I would like to know what are the constraints regarding the combinations of events, times and OLD and NEW.

Comment: Given what rigger are used for a lot of that doesn't make sense. I think the after insert section is a typo though because they talk about how it doesn't support old as well. It only makes sense for it to have new values because those the ones you are putting in and there will be no old values because the record is new.  Update triggers should have both old and new available because sometimes what you want is to record both sets of values for audit purposes. Delete can only have old values because it is an existing record that is being dropped so there is no new information except nulls/

Comment: Thank you for you comments.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of items mentioned in the documentation:

[19.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

- > In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old
  >   row.
- > (Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger because the
  >   row change will have already occurred.)

It is perfectly valid to use `NEW` in `AFTER`, but is not valid `SET NEW... := ...;`

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `insert_emplyee_history` AFTER INSERT ON `EMPLOYEE`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `EMPLOYEE_HISTORY`
  VALUES
  (NEW.`NOME`, NEW.`SSN`, NEW.`SALARIO`, NEW.`DNO`);
  -- SET NEW.`NOME` := 'NOME' -- NOT VALID IN AFTER
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5457/1)</kbd>

Comment: Yes...Indeed. You are right. Thank you for the clarification.